# Angular HttpClient get request does not contain 'Origin' header in production mode

Tags: angular

In my Angular cli application (currently using Angular 7), I am using HttpClient to send get and post requests to a web api.

In development environment the is **Origin** header in the request headers for both get and post requests.

The issue is in Production mode - which there the Origin header is being sent only for post requests, but does not exist in the get requests.

production mode I mean after building the app as following:

```
ng build --aot --prod
```

I need this header in all types of requests.

How can I "force" it to be included also in GET requests? Why is the behavior different?

Comment: What is causing that to be an issue?

Comment: for some specific needs I need this header in the server

Comment: Could you elaborate on them? Headers are easily spoofed, relying on them may cause issues.